# htaccess that redirects non-https to https site causing pages that should be 404 to show the homepage instead. How do i fix this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have little to no experience with htaccess so this may be incredibly simple to fix. The following is in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is used to 301 redirect anyone accessing my sites old non https address and send them to the https version. It also directs the `url.co.uk` version to the `www.url.co.uk`version.

Since using this, I've noticed that 404 pages no longer show and any time it should, the user is taken to the homepage instead. What needs changed/added to show the 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy in this case, simply add

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Change the doc as required

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and it didn't work but i suspect it's a Joomla issue (which I'm using) since i have another Joomla site with the same htaccess file which works fine.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about Joomla but this is a standard technique in the IaaS world. So yes, you're probably right! If you find the solution do post it with context to help the community.